# Non-equi join of two tables

Tags: r, non-equi-join

I have 2 dataframes where I need to find how many times the entries in mock$num fall within the range of x-y specified by the range dataframe.

```
id <- c(1:9)
num <- c(99,101,199,250,999,1500,3000,4000,5000)
mock <- data.frame(id, num)

x <- c(100,100,200,1000,4000,4000)
y <- c(198,200,300,2000,5000,5000)
range <- data.frame(x,y)
```

The desired output is shown below

```
id num check
1 99   0
2 101  2
3 199  1
4 250  1
5 999  0
6 1500 1
7 3000 0
8 4000 2
9 5000 2
```

which can be obtained by the following code

```
mock$check <- mapply(
    function(x){
        count = 0
        for (i in 1:nrow(range)){
            if (x >= range$x[i] & x <= range$y[i]){
                count = count + 1
            }
        }
        paste0(count)
    },
    mock$num
)
```

The above approach is unsuitable for large datasets due to the for loop and I was trying to use a non-equi join method (via `data.table`). However, I am stuck as to how to do a non-equi join between two tables (not sure how to proceed to...)

```
nonequi <- mock[range, on =.(num >= x, num <=y),]
```

Would like to seek some guidance to this problem. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

First do non-equi join then summarise for each `id` how many times it appears and join back to `mock` to find out which ids were left out. For those ids set count to zero.

```
res <- setDT(mock)[setDT(range), .(id), on = .(num >= x, num <= y)][, .N, by = id][mock, on = .(id)][is.na(N), N := 0][]
```

Answer (score 2):

not sure about the execution speed for large data arrays

```r
id <- c(1:9)
num <- c(99,101,199,250,999,1500,3000,4000,5000)
mock <- data.frame(id, num)

x <- c(100,100,200,1000,4000,4000)
y <- c(198,200,300,2000,5000,5000)
RANGE <- data.frame(x,y)

mock$check <- sapply(mock$num, function(z) sum(z >= RANGE$x & z <= RANGE$y))

mock
#>   id  num check
#> 1  1   99     0
#> 2  2  101     2
#> 3  3  199     1
#> 4  4  250     1
#> 5  5  999     0
#> 6  6 1500     1
#> 7  7 3000     0
#> 8  8 4000     2
#> 9  9 5000     2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>